# angularjs minification issue with controller

Tags: angularjs, bundling-and-minification

Here's my controller:

```
angular.module('domiciliations').controller('mandatsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Domiciliation', 'logger', function ($scope, Domiciliation, logger) {
    $scope.mandats = Domiciliation.query();

    $scope.fullName = function () {
        return this.Person ? 'test' : 'test2'
    }

    $scope.isNextDisabled = function () {
        return false;
    }

    $scope.isPrevDisabled = function () {
        return true;
    }

    $scope.next = function () {
        logger.info("test");
    }
}]);
```

When minified, I get an error:

```
Error: Unknown provider: nProvider <- n
```

Now, if I include the following line after my controller, then it works:

```
mandatsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'Domiciliation', 'logger'];
```

I thought the whole point of having the array type declaration in the controller function, was to avoid having to use $inject.... Did I miss something ?

Comment: How do you do `mandatsCtrl.$inject...` when it is an anonymous functions? There's something in your code you're not showing us.

Comment: you did not miss anything for code minification you have to use any of below two approach

Comment: @Martin, hum.. good point. There's nothing more in my code than what I've shown here. I guess javascript does not care the function does not exist as it is created at runtime by angular (I suppose so anyway...)

Comment: Could it be that you have declared both a controller on the module with the name `mandatsCtrl` AND a global function with the same name?

Comment: @Martin, ok you were right, there was some files I forgot about, which were used instead and where I've defined the mandatsCtrl variable... my bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you were to minify the JavaScript code for  controller, all of its function arguments would be minified as well, and the dependency injector would not be able to identify services correctly.
There are two ways to handle minification in angular

```
1)Just assign an array with service identifier strings into the $inject property of the controller function
 mandatsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'Domiciliation', 'logger'];

2) Using bracketnotation
var mandatsCtrl= ['$scope', 'Domiciliation','logger' function($scope, $Domiciliation,logger) { /* constructor body */ }];
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

Comment: That's what the PO has done (approach 2). How is this a solution to the PO's problem when it's reiterating the same approach?

Comment: I want to explain that the code mentioned in question is not a problem its just how angular work in case code is minified

Comment: @Ajay, thanks for clarifying, although I'm totally aware of all that already :) My point is that I did use the bracket notation, but I still have to use the $inject property, otherwise I'm getting the error.

Comment: Yes just see this link for documentation on angularsite   http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

Comment: `var mandatsCtrl= ['$scope', 'Domiciliation', 'logger',  function($scope, $Domiciliation,logger) { /* constructor body */ }];`
You forgot to add the ',' between "logger" and "function" for the bracket notation ex.

Comment: I applied both methods, just worked PERFECT! Thanks!